# COGNOS - How to sum the last 12 row values

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-11

I need to sum the last 12 of a `value` for EVERY ROW. On SQL this looks like it:

```
sum(value) over (partition by field1, field2
            order by field3 asc rows BETWEEN 11 preceding AND CURRENT row
        ) AS total_acum
```

I can't do that on the database and need to do that on the Cognos... Any tip?

Obs.:

- I'm using the version 11.1 R7
- I'm using the Cognos in Portuguese. Because of that, i'm using `;` and not `,` on the formulas.
  Edit2:
  The answer given by @C'est Moi, is pretty much what i want. But i'm keep having errors and i have no idea why.

@C'est Moi tells to use the code:

```
running-total ( QUANTITY
for
Period ( _add_months ( order_day_date, -12) , order_day_date)
)
```

But when i do that, i got this error messages:

Try 1 My code (with ;):

```
running-total ( [total] for period( _add_months ( [date]; -12) ; [date]) )
```

Try 1 Error:

```
XQE-V5-0017 Erro de sintaxe V5 localizado para o item de dados ''query_field_name'' da consulta ''cognos_query'', token inválido ";" localizado após "running-total ( [total] for period( _add_months ( [date]; -12) ". CAF-WRN-2082 ... O CAF ... log com o SecureErrorID:2021-01-18-12:36:58.114-#874
```

Try 2 My code (with ,):

```
running-total ( [total] for period( _add_months ( [date]; -12) , [date]) )
```

Try 2 Error:

```
XQE-V5-0017 Erro de sintaxe V5 localizado para o item de dados ''query_field_name'' da consulta ''cognos_query'', token inválido " " localizado após "running-total ( [total] for period( _add_months( [date]; -12) ,". CAF-WRN-2082 Ocorreu um erro. Entre em contato com o administrador. O CAF registrou o erro completo no log com o SecureErrorID:2021-01-18-12:53:54.959-#891
```

Edit 3:
I'm starting to think that this is some kind of configuration that is'nt right and dont let me use dimentional functions... Does anyone know something about that?

Answer (score 1):

moving-total would be what you would want.  It would require that your report is ordered.

Running total for period might be what you want.

running-total ( QUANTITY

for

Period ( _add_months ( order_day_date, -12) , order_day_date)

)

Comment: I edit my question to be mode clear about the new problem. Can you help?

Comment: Not much other than explain the error a bit. The symbol separating parameters in the functions is causing the cognos query engine to be confused.  It is expecting a comma.  In some locales the symbol for separators is different.  If things had been properly done the symbol in the UI would be not directly passed to the query engine but intermediated by code which would substitute the locale-specific separator symbol for the separator symbol which the query engine needs, but it hasn't. :(

Comment: A token should be a token and the particular value for it in a locale should not bugger up things but it looks like it does.  Log a bug with IBM.